# Catch Exception, set previous, re-throw

Tags: php, exception

I've got a bit of code that sends a message first over UDP, and if the message is truncated it raises an exception and retries over TCP. If *that* call generates an exception I would like to throw *both* exceptions to denote the exact manner in which the code has failed.

Ideally I would take the second exception and set its `$previous` to the first exception and re-throw like so:

```
try {
    $this->sendQueryUDP($packet);
    return $this->getResponseUDP($packet->getID());
} catch(TruncatedUDPPacketException $u) {
    try {
        return $this->sendQueryTCP($packet);
    } catch(\Exception $t) {
        $t->setPrevious($u); // this function doesn't exist!
        throw $t;
    }
}
```

However, the only way I can see to set `$previous` is in `Exception`'s constructor.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call this *better*, but here is a way to do it:

```
private function setPreviousException($e, $prev) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($e);
    $prop = $reflection->getProperty('previous');
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    $prop->setValue($e, $prev);
    $prop->setAccessible(false);
    return $e;
}
```

and then

```
try {
    $this->sendQueryUDP($packet);
    return $this->getResponseUDP($packet->getID());
} catch(TruncatedUDPPacketException $u) {
    try {
        return $this->sendQueryTCP($packet);
    } catch(\Exception $t) {
        $this->setPreviousException($t, $u);
        throw $t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Short of extending or redefining Exception this is probably the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add to @dave's answer, I discovered that `ReflectionClass` doesn't necessarily "collapse" extended classes and setting `$previous` on a class descended from `Exception` would cause an error. eg:

```
class FooException extends Exception {}

$one = new Exception('one');
$two = new FooException('two');

var_dump(setPreviousException($two, $one));
```

Generates:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Property previous does not exist'
```

To address this I needed to drill down to the parent class using `ReflectionClass::getParentClass()` like so:

```
protected function setPreviousException(\Exception $e, \Exception $prev) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($e);
    while( ! $reflection->hasProperty('previous') ) {
        $reflection = $reflection->getParentClass();
    }
    $prop = $reflection->getProperty('previous');
    $prop->setAccessible('true');
    $prop->setValue($e, $prev);
    $prop->setAccessible('false');
    return $e;
}
```

I've also had a bit of back-and-forth with some other PHP devs and using code like this to override `Exception::$previous` has the side effect of "changing history" and, unless you're certain that `$e` will never already have a previous exception, set you should probably not do something like this.

As well, in practice this doesn't necessarily make debugging any clearer. The stack trace generated by the later exception contains the useful information, and the trace from the initial, handled exception generally confuses the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Another apporach like a magic.

```php
private function setPreviousException(\Throwable $e, \Throwable $prev): \Throwable
{
    try {
        try {
            throw $prev;
        } finally {
            throw $e;
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

It has some advantages:

- It can handle `parent::$previous`.
- It can append to the tail of existing `$previous` chain

Link: [$previous 引数を取らない例外クラスに強引に例外をチェーンする裏ワザ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mpyw/items/7f5a9fe6472f38352d96)

Comment: That a great solution, but you have a type in `Thowable`, need to be `Throwable` ;)