# Set previous exception not throgh constructor

Tags: php, exception

**tl:dr**

Is is possible to set the previous exception without being through the constructor?

---

We're using a base exception which already multiple arguments, I don't intend to add more (if possible).
So what I though is to add a method `withPrevious(\Exception $e)` to the base exception. So it could be used like:

```
catch(SomeException $e) {
    throw new SpecificException($arg1, $arg2)->withPrevious($e);
}
```

However I couldn't find any kind of setter for the previous exception, I really think it must be set by the `__construct()`

Any idea if is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch Exception, set previous, re-throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576141/catch-exception-set-previous-re-throw)